# QML label inflate background rect

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Okay, I give up. How do I draw backing rectangle around `Label`?

Here's what I do

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Label {
    id: label
    text: root.text
    font {
        pointSize: 24
        bold: true
    }
    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    background: Rectangle{
        radius: 20
        color: "lightgreen"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width + 30
        height: parent.height + 30
    }
}
```

And that sure draws rounded rect around `Label`, but the size of the label stays the same, so layout can't position it right. How the heck do I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `padding`. Don't add anything to the height/width of the background. Just add `padding`.

```
Label {
    id: label
    text: root.text
    font {
        pointSize: 24
        bold: true
    }
    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    padding: 15
    background: Rectangle{
        radius: 20
        color: "lightgreen"
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. I can't believe I've lost so much time looking for that. Thank you